# linear layout not separating my added views

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a linear layout and I'm adding new children to it programmatically. However, they are all stacking on top of each other on the z-axis when I expected they would stack on the y-axis. what am I missing?

the layout is:

featured.xml (the container with the following children)

- featured_tab.xml
- featured_tab.xml
- featured_tab.xml
- featured_tab.xml
- featured_tab.xml

## featured.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</LinearLayout>
```

## featured_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/featuredContentBtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/featuredContentImg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/featuredContentBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:contentDescription="Featured Content Image" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tabGradient"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/featuredContentBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/featured_tab_gradient"
        android:contentDescription="Tab Gradient" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

## Code

*to add the featured_tabs to the featured*

```
private void loadTabs() {
        Document doc = XMLParser.getDOM(Featured._xml);
        NodeList featuredNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName(Featured.TAG_FEATURE);

        this.removeAllViews();

        // loop through all featured nodes <Feature>
        for (int i = 0; i < featuredNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            FeaturedTab tab = (FeaturedTab)MainActivity.instance.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.featured_tab, null);
            Element element = (Element)featuredNodes.item(i);
            tab.setTitle(XMLParser.getValue(element, Featured.TAG_TITLE));
            tab.setImageURL(XMLParser.getValue(element, Featured.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
            tab.setLinkURL(XMLParser.getValue(element, Featured.TAG_LINK_URL));
            this.addView(tab);
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `featured.xml` to actually be a `LinearLayout` and give it an ID:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/featured_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

And in your code, get that LinearLayout and add the other layouts to id programmatically

```
LinearLayout featured = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.featured_linear_layout);

for (int i = 0; i < featuredNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            FeaturedTab tab = (FeaturedTab)MainActivity.instance.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.featured_tab, null);
            Element element = (Element)featuredNodes.item(i);
            tab.setTitle(XMLParser.getValue(element, Featured.TAG_TITLE));
            tab.setImageURL(XMLParser.getValue(element, Featured.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
            tab.setLinkURL(XMLParser.getValue(element, Featured.TAG_LINK_URL));
            featured.addView(tab);
        }
```